# Redirect to https and www not working

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I know this has been asked 1,000 times but none of the other answers have helped, so here we are.

I need to redirect:

http://example.com to https://www.example.com

http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com

Here are my rules:

```
<rule name="HTTP Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>

<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Result:

http://example.com redirects to https://www.example.com

http://www.example.com redirects to http://www.example.com (no SSL)

I can't seem to get this to work properly.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with your initial HTTP to HTTPS rule.

Try this:

```
 <rule name="HTTP Redirect to HTTPS" patternSyntax="Wildcard" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>

    <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Thank you @Calvin. I had tried this before but was getting into an endless redirect loop. After contacting the host, the issue turned out to be that the load balancer was terminating the SSL requests, which caused the endless redirection loop. I appreciate the answer though.

Comment: No problem. I would think the endless loop would be caused by you having pattern="on" rather than off. Nevertheless, glad it is solved.

Comment: I know, right? It was driving me nuts. Every time I set it to `off`, it went into the endless loop. That is why I had it `on`.